# How to crete a new .net core project in the Yeoman generator

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm writing a Yeoman generator. How can I call

```
dotnet new
```

inside my generator? 
Is there a better way to create a new .net core project in yeoman generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to call `dotnet new` directly.

```
const { execSync, exec } = require('child_process');

function formated_exec_sync(command) {
    console.log("exec->" + command);
    execSync(command, {stdio: 'inherit'});
}

function new_solution(name) {
    formated_exec_sync(`dotnet new sln --name ${name}`);
}

function new_console_project(name) {
    formated_exec_sync(`dotnet new console -lang "C#" --name ${name}`);
}

function add_project_to_solution(project_name, solution_name) {
    formated_exec_sync(`dotnet sln ${solution_name}.sln add ${project_name}`);
}

function add_package_to_project(package, project, version = null) {
    let command = `dotnet add ${project} package`;
    if (version != null)
        command += ` --version ${version}`;
    command += ` ${package}`
    formated_exec_sync(command);
}

module.exports = {
    new_solution,
    new_console_project,
    add_project_to_solution,
    add_package_to_project,
}
```